# CSRF token for MERN stack doesn't work on iPhone browsers

Tags: node.js, express, csrf, mern

I read a few pages here about CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) attacks and how to defend your app against them, but I still need help. So, here I am, implementing a full-stack MERN app hosted in different domains. The server part (Node.js and Express) I deployed using Railway.app, and the front-end (React) is deployed in Netlify. I'm using MongoDB Atlas Cloud for now. I was using the HttpOnly cookie setting for the token (not a bearer, because cookies are more secure, so they said). I was happy, and everything was a bright sky until I started hardening the website and putting the CSRF protection.

After securing my Node.js server.js file with the library csurf (npm i csurf), the app worked fine using my macOS browser (any browser) but doesn't work at all using my iPhone's browser. The error I catch is:

```
ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token
at csrf (/app/node_modules/csurf/index.js:112:19)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:328:13)
at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:9
at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
at urlencodedParser (/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:82:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:328:13)
at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:9
```

So, I realized if I check the iPhone Settings option "Allow Cross-Website Tracking" to true, my login works. Otherwise, if this option is set to false, I receive a 403 eror and the exception is attached above from Railway's logs.

Since my website will be commercial, I cannot ask every single mobile user to please unselect this mobile option. Also, there must be something terrible configured in my server.js that I have no idea what. Could someone please help me here? What should I do?

Here is my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const jwtDecode = require("jwt-decode");
const { expressjwt: jwt } = require("express-jwt");
const csrf = require("csurf");
const csrfProtection = csrf({
    cookie: {
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "lax", // I tried 'none' as well and it doesn't work.
    },
});

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

//Middlewere
// Set up CORS configuration
const clientOrigin =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
        ? "https://MY_REAL_REACT_WEBSITE.com"
        : "http://localhost:3000";

const corsOptions = {
    origin: clientOrigin,
    credentials: true,
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    optionSuccessStatus: 200,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(cookieParser());
const checkJwt = jwt({
    secret: process.env.TOKEN_SECRET,
    algorithms: ["HS256"],
    getToken: (req) => {
        if (req.cookies && req.cookies.token) {
            return req.cookies.token;
        }
        return null;
    },
}).unless({ path: ["/login", "/csrfToken", "/createUser", "/logout"] });
app.use(checkJwt);

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "10mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "10mb" }));

app.use(csrfProtection); // ----> HERE IS THE GUY

const port = process.env.PORT || 5001;

app.use(express.json());

app.use(require("./routes/serverRoutes")); // My routes are elsewhere

const attachUser = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies.token;
    if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Authentication invalid" });
    }

    const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);

    if (!decodedToken) {
        return res
            .status(401)
            .json({ message: "There was a problem authorizing the request" });
    } else {
        req.userId = decodedToken;
        next();
    }
};
app.use(attachUser);

// This displays a message that the server is running and listening to the specified port
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: "*The server part I deployed using Railway.app, and the front-end is deployed in Netlify.*" - does that mean they are deployed on two separate domains? Then **that** is your problem, with the iphone (and probably other) browsers rejecting the third-party cookie.

Comment: Yes, but nowadays, almost all applications are distributed in different domains, right? How do they solve this?

Comment: No, a web application runs under one single domain. It might be hosted on different servers and be split into many services, but they are all served under the same domain using a reverse proxy, or at least subdomains (which IIRC don't count as third-party). Sometimes external APIs are called directly from the frontend, using CORS, sometimes assets are included form external CDNs, but the main application and API usually runs at the same domain.

Comment: Thanks, Bergi. I'll explore this option a little further.